# Android SDK SignerFactory throwing exception

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, authentication, identity, amazon-polly

I'm building an Android application with AWS Cognito and Polly. The app worked fine until today when it started trowing an `IllegalArgumentException` in the `auth.SignerFactory.createSigner` function.

I have the following code:

```
mCredentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            appContext,
            COGNITO_POOL_ID,
            Regions.US_EAST_1);
    Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<>();
    logins.put("graph.facebook.com", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
    mCredentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
    //setup amazon polly
    mPollyClient = new AmazonPollyPresigningClient(mCredentialsProvider);
```

And the exception thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.amazonaws.auth.SignerFactory.createSigner(SignerFactory.java:115)
at com.amazonaws.auth.SignerFactory.lookupAndCreateSigner(SignerFactory.java:104)
at com.amazonaws.auth.SignerFactory.getSigner(SignerFactory.java:79)
at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.computeSignerByServiceRegion(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:379)
at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.computeSignerByURI(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:351)
at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.setEndpoint(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:215)
at com.amazonaws.services.polly.AmazonPollyClient.init(AmazonPollyClient.java:281)
at com.amazonaws.services.polly.AmazonPollyClient.<init>(AmazonPollyClient.java:261)
at com.amazonaws.services.polly.AmazonPollyPresigningClient.<init>(AmazonPollyPresigningClient.java:128)
at com.amazonaws.services.polly.AmazonPollyPresigningClient.<init>(AmazonPollyPresigningClient.java:107)
at com.amazonaws.services.polly.AmazonPollyPresigningClient.<init>(AmazonPollyPresigningClient.java:76)
at com.example.mymirrorlinkapplication.MainActivity.initializeLex(MainActivity.java:552)
at com.example.mymirrorlinkapplication.MainActivity.checkFacebookLogin(MainActivity.java:298)
at com.example.mymirrorlinkapplication.MainActivity.checkPermissions(MainActivity.java:289)
```

I tried changing from `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` to `CognitoCredentialsProvider`, but the result is the same. What could be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code where you're extracting the value of the Facebook Access Token from the Access Token object may be incorrect. At least based on the Facebook docs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
}
```

I'm assuming that AccessToken has already been instantiated and populated. You may need to update your code which inserts the token into the logins map to this:

```
logins.put("graph.facebook.com",AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
```